# Install Let's Encript in a custom docker container

Tags: docker, apache2, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm trying to get https enabled on a web server (apache) already running in a custom docker instance for a specific web app.  The container seems to be running `Alpine Linux`.  Before a few weeks ago, I barely knew what docker was.  Also, I didn't set up or install the docker container myself.

I'm able to `exec sh` into the container just fine and have even tweaked the apache config file before.

I searched for some tutorials, but they all seem to go off into variants that don't apply here, such as editing the docker config files, before actually starting the docker instance.  (Actually, if that is the best way, I would still like to get some clear steps on that.

What I'm looking for is something along the lines of installing certbot in the container and then running it from there.  Are there steps to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Certbot is just a client, it is not supported on Alpine.

If you would like to use letsencrypt in a container, try acme-client.

Comment: ok, I've found 2 docker clients from here: https://letsencrypt.org/docs/client-options/.  1.tls_certificate_generation 2.ZeroSSL  The first one seems to want you to run their docker container and the second one, has some rather obtuse aws commands to run, without much documentation on how to get those parameters or where to run those commands.